# SilverStripe Template - how to access keyless values

Tags: silverstripe

How can I show a 2 dimensional array as html table per SS template? Since there are just values and no keys for the Child/Row DO I'm struggling to show theme per template. How do I call theme in template or how would you do?

array showItems

```
0 =
    0 = Title
    1 = Text
    ...
1 =
    0 = Title
    1 = Text
    ...
...
```

PHP

```
public function showItems() {
    $result = ArrayList::create();
    $table = $this->getItems();
    foreach ($table as $row) {
        $r = DataObject::create($row);
        $result->push($r);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Template:

```
<% if $showItems %>
    <table>
    <% loop $showItems %> // loop for rows
        <tr>
        <% loop $Children %> // loop for cells
            <td>$Me</td>
        <% end_loop %>
        </tr>
    <% end_loop %>
    </table>
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: what's the return value of the method getItems() ? An array ? Please provide an example.

Comment: @derRobert a array example is added. first array contains rows, nested array contains cells. I can loop over rows but found no way to make cells and values visible except to create the table in php :(

Answer (score 0):

Use [ArrayData](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-ArrayData.html) for each row, but as you know what each column is standing for I'd add keys to it, e.g. using [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Untested:

```
public function showItems() {
    $result = ArrayList::create();
    $table = $this->getItems();
    $keys = array('ID', 'Foo', 'Bar');
    foreach ($table as $row) {
        $r = ArrayData::create(array_combine($keys, $row));
        $result->push($r);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Another possibility:

```
public function showItems() {
    $result = ArrayList::create();
    $table = $this->getItems();

    foreach ($table as $row) {
        $r = ArrayList::create($row)); //you can oop over an ArrayList
        $result->push($r);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

In your template you might do:

```
<% if $showItems %>
    <table>
    <% loop $showItems %> // loop for rows
        <tr>
            <td>$ID - $Foo</td>
            <td>$Bar</td>
        </tr>
    <% end_loop %>
    </table>
<% end_if %>
```

Another possibility:

```
public function showItems() {
    $result = ArrayList::create();
    $table = $this->getItems();

    foreach ($table as $row) {
        $r = ArrayData::create(array('Row' => ArrayList::create($row)))); //you can oop over an ArrayList
        $result->push($r);
    }
    return $result;
}

<% if $showItems %>
    <table>
    <% loop $showItems %> // loop for rows
        <tr>
        <% loop $Row %>
            <td>$Me</td> //dunno if that really works...
        <% end_loop %>
        </tr>
    <% end_loop %>
    </table>
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: hi @wmk - thanks you for your  answer! In this case table cells are "unknown" (amount & name can differ). So this is not the solution I've imagined. Guess I have to stick with PHP.

Comment: You could still try $0 and $1 ... in the template

or convert your array to an nested ArrayList...

Comment: @munomono you should remap your data so that the position n and n+1 are simplified to $key $value. In your case it every 2 values starts a new pair. That way its easier to handle the rendering on the template. Otherwise you, as you said, generate the output on the model.